# Inadvertent Infinite loop

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I'm just beginning Python, and while trying out an exercise in Ardit Suice's course, I wrote the following code to implement a custom website blocker:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
import os
from datetime import datetime as dt
hosts_path = '/etc/hosts'
tmp_path = '/tmp/hosts.tmp'
site_list = [ 'www.facebook.com', 'mail.google.com']

def write_hosts():
    hostfile = open(hosts_path, 'r')
    filecont = hostfile.read()
    hostfile.close
    for site in site_list:
        if not site in filecont:
            try:
                with open(hosts_path, 'a') as fh:
                    fh.write('127.0.1.1 ' + site + '\n')
                    print ("Wrote %s to hosts file %s" % (site, hosts_path))
            except PermissionError:
                print ("Sorry, you need to be admin to do this")

def write_fresh_hosts():
    testfile = open(tmp_path, 'w')
    hostfile = open(hosts_path, 'r')
    line=hostfile.readline()
    while line:
        for site in site_list:
            if not site in line:
                testfile.write(line)
            else:
                print ("Deleting %s from our blocked list" % site)
        line=hostfile.readline()

    testfile.close
    hostfile.close
    os.rename(tmp_path, hosts_path)

while True:
    print(1)
    print (dt.now())
    upper=dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day, 20, 0)
    lower=dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day, 17, 0)
    if lower <= dt.now() <= upper:
        print ("Blocking now")
        write_hosts()
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        print ("Checking website lists for already blocked sites:")
        write_fresh_hosts()
        time.sleep(5)
```

What I wanted to do, was to write a list of sites to the hosts file during a specified time interval, and to delete those lines if the time was outside those hours.

However I found that my hosts file quickly grew to 110MB size, and it just contained the line `127.0.0.1       localhost` repeated over and over:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
... (repeated)
```

While at the end of my file, I found the lines:

```
127.0.1.1   www.facebook.com
127.0.1.1   mail.google.com
```

Originally the hosts file had only contained the single line:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Output:

```
sudo python siteblocker.py 
Checking website lists for already blocked sites:
Checking website lists for already blocked sites:
... (repeated)
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: also you're not really closing your files. that could be an issue when you rename afterwards...

Comment: Could you explain why the while loop with readline is a problem?

Comment: it's not very good but it's not infinite. I missed the readline in the loop. The close issue is real, though. Use `.close()` with parentheses.

Comment: I added parentheses for close. It's still writing an infinite number of lines to the hosts file. I would like to add that currently my time is outside the 'blocking' time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of your code:

```
while line:
    for site in site_list:
        if not site in line:
            testfile.write(line)
        else:
            print ("Deleting %s from our blocked list" % site)
    line=hostfile.readline()
```

You are iterating over your `site_list` for every line of the host file. Every time the given `site` isn't found within `line`, you are writing `line`. Since there are two entries in your `site_list`, and neither of them are in your `localhost` line, you write each line twice.

Since you then make the newly generated output file your new input file, you are effectively doubling the number of lines in the file with every call.

Comment: So what I need is a `break` immediately after I write the line, I guess.